# Parameter expansion in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

To retrieve strings of the following pattern from a text file populated with multiple entries:

```
entry=G_1234
entry=G_5678
entry=G_2345
```

The following grep statement doesn't provide any result

```
grep -ioe "entry=G_{1234,2345}" filename
```

Could you kindly guide as to where is the mistake or if parameter expansion is not possible in grep?

Comment: The parameter expansion will not take place between quotes. And if you manage to get it work how would `grep` use that expansion? Why not using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

```
grep -iEo 'entry=G_(1234|2345)'
```

That is use the alternation operator of extended (`E`) regular expressions.

Or with shells that support brace expansion, use:

```
grep -io '-eentry=G_'{1234,2345}
```

The shell would then expand it to:

```
grep -io -eentry=G_1234 -eentry=G_2345
```

Causing grep to look for either of those 2 **e**xpressions.

Answer (score 1):

Grep uses regular expressions, not shell patterns. Regular expressions have different syntax:

```
grep -ioe 'entry=G_\(1234\|2345\)' filename
```

Comment: Note that `\|` is a GNU extension as standard BRE don't have an alternation operator. (-o is a GNU extension as well anyway, so it's probably OK for the OP).